# Changing button event after button click in C#

Tags: c#, button, text, click

I've a form that navigates webpage and access data. It looks like something below.

```
 private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(LoginButton.Text == Login)
        {
                LoginButton.Text = "Logging in...";
                ....
                ...
                Login process goes here...
                ..
                if(Login Successed)
                {
                    LoginButton.Text ="Download";
                }
                else
                {
                    LoginButton.Text = "Login";
                }
        }
        else if(LoginButton.Text==Download)
        {
            Download data here...
        }
    }
```

Same button(And same event too), doing two process and seems like different events with a label.
1) If there any problem like inefficiency run?
2) Any alternate ways to do this like different flag schemes?
3) Any method to have with more than one event for same button to achieve same idea?

Thanks.

Comment: try with case and see...3) more than one event for the button is not good idea i thin (if possible)

Comment: You may try register/unregister event handler programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If there any problem like inefficiency run?

Button clicks run at human time.  You can burn half a billion cpu instructions without inconveniencing the user.

2) Any alternate ways to do this like different flag schemes?

Using the Text property of the button is fragile, your code will break when somebody decides to change the button text or when you localize your app to another language.  A simple private bool field in your class is much better.

3) Any method to have with more than one event for same button to achieve same idea?

No.  You could of course use two buttons, placed on top of each other and one of them always hidden.  Makes localization much simpler and you'll get that bool field for free.

Comment: Don't adding a button extra increase the payload during execution?

Comment: Well of course.  But you are again making the same mistake, you have no clue whether that's actually a problem.  The cheapest window by a long shot is an invisible one.  As is code you don't have to write.

Answer (score 1):

like Daniel A. White said
have two buttons

may be on some event like oncreate/onload do check..jst a pseudo code

```
 if process is login then
 do 
   //then showLoginButton
    btnlogin.visible

 else
     //download
    btndonload.visible
```

inside the login button

```
        if(Login Successed)
            {
                 btndonload.visible
            }
            else
            {
                LoginButton.Text = "Login";
            }
```

this may be better with two buttons then single..and cleaner also

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code. This gives some alternate ideas too.

Answer (score 1):

**Write custom event handlers for the mouseClick**

Write separate methods for login and download.

**Register your custom event handlers to the button click event**

I assume there is some logic that decides that the button text should be "download" or "login". At that point, set the button text of course, but also register the appropriate event handler.

**This will allow you to have a single button that does *anything***

```
protected void Login_MouseClickHandler (object obj ,MouseClickEventArgs e) {
    // login logic
    // this would be the logic you say is "inside the login button"
}

protected void Download_MouseClickHandler (object obj ,MouseClickEventArgs e) {
    // download logic
}


// pseudo code
// note that there is only one button
if process is login then
    theButton.text = "login"
    theButton.MouseClick += new MouseClickEventHandler(Login_MouseClickHandler)
else  
   button.text = "download"
   theButton.MouseClick += new MouseClickEventHandler (Download_MouseClickHandler)
end if
```

**Software Design Thoughts**

- Easier to extend. We don't need another button for every new thing to do
- Separation of Concerns - All login code, for example, is in a separate method that does *only* login stuff.
- Change is isolated and minimized. Writing new, separate methods is less error prone than in-lining that code in your `if else` structure. And consequently the `if else` structure is kept simple and comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea use the text as the state. Ideally, you should have 2 buttons that fire different events and call out the main logic to a presenter in the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use control containers such as Panel and GroupBox. You can have a whole bunch of Panels for controls in different states.